# Split data frame by multiple treatment groups?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a data frame with six treatment groups where treatment group is indicated with "1" in one of six variables/columns (NA otherwise) that looks something like this.

```
      V1  V2  V3   V4  V5  V6
1     1   NA   NA  NA  NA  NA
2     NA  1   NA   NA  NA  NA 
3     NA  NA  NA   1   NA  NA
```

I want to split the larger dataset into multiple subsets/sub-dataframes in order to look at each six groups individually. I know the usual way to do this is with

`split(x, f, drop = FALSE, ...)`

but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it without repeating the process for each f group, where f depends on the value of each one of the six variables. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Comment: As multiple data frames or lists, I think. I'm interested in descriptives and mean values of other variables based on belonging to groups 1-6.

Comment: `split(df, which(df == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 'col'])`

Comment: @alistaire - on a similar idea - `split(df, col(df)[!is.na(df)])`

Comment: ooh, or `split(df, max.col(!is.na(df)))`

Comment: @alistaire This isn't the full dataframe though, just the variables by which i'm splitting. Would it then be split (df, max.com(!is.na(df$[V1;V2;V3;V4;V5V6])))?

Comment: @IG114 - something like that - `split(df, max.col(!is.na(df[c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5","V6")])))` to be exact.

Comment: You should not store indicator data in columns as column headers. Your data should be in long format with groups as observations. Consider reshaping then subset logically.